# Subdocument index in mongo

Tags: mongodb, indexing

What exactly happens when I call `ensureIndex(data)` when typical data looks like `data:{name: "A",age:"B", job : "C"}` ? Will it create a compound index over these three fields or will it create only one index applicable when anything from data is requested or something altogether different ?

Comment: It's easy to check. Just create a test collection and fire a couple of queries with `.explain()`. That's what I would do. I myself am not sure what mongo will do.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can do either :

```
> db.collection.ensureIndex({"data.name": 1,"data.age":1, "data.job" : 1})
> db.collection.ensureIndex({"data": 1})
```

This is discussed in the documentation under [indexes-on-embedded-fields](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-single/#indexes-on-embedded-fields) and [indexes on sub documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-single/#indexes-on-subdocuments)

The important section of the sub document section is *'When performing equality matches on subdocuments, field order matters and the subdocuments must match exactly.'*

This means that the 2 indexes are the same for simple queries .

However, as the sub-document example shows, you can get some interesting results (that you might not expect) if you just index the whole sub-document as opposed to a specific field and then do a comparison operator (like `$gte`) - if you index a specific sub field you get a less flexible, but potentially more useful index.

It really all depends on your use case.

Anyway, once you have created the index you can check what's created with :

```
> db.collection.getIndexes()
[
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "test.collection",
    "name" : "_id_"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "data.name" : 1,
        "data.age" : 1,
        "data.job" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "test.collection",
    "name" : "data.name_1_data.age_1_data.job_1"
}
```

]

As you can see from the output it created a new key called `data.name_1_data.age_1_data.job_1` (the `_id_` index is always created).

If you want to test your new index then you can do :

```
> db.collection.insert({data:{name: "A",age:"B", job : "C"}})
> db.collection.insert({data:{name: "A1",age:"B", job : "C"}})
> db.collection.find({"data.name" : "A"}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor data.name_1_data.age_1_data.job_1",
     .... more stuff
```

The main thing is that you can see that your new index was used (**BtreeCursor data.name_1_data.age_1_data.job_1** in the cursor field is what indicates this is the case). If you see `"cursor" : "BasicCursor"`, then your index was not used.

For more detailed information look [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/#indexing-strategies).

Answer (score -3):

you can try this :

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({"data.name": 1,"data.age":1, "data.job" : 1})
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, namely what is the result of doing this.

Comment: This is not helpful. The point of this kind of question is saving time for people with a similar question.