# Ensuring index for nested repeating entities

Tags: java, mongodb, indexing, database

I need to enforce unique constraint on a nested document, for example:

```
urlEntities: [ 
{ "url" : "http://t.co/ujBNNRWb0y" , "display_url" : "bit.ly/11JyiVp" ,  "expanded_url" :
"http://bit.ly/11JyiVp"} , 
{ "url" : "http://t.co/DeL6RiP8KR" , "display_url" : "ow.ly/i/2HC9x" , 
"expanded_url" : "http://ow.ly/i/2HC9x"}
]
```

`url`, `display_url`, and `expaned_url` need to be unique. How to issue `ensureIndex` command for this condition in MongoDB?

Also, is it a good design to have nested documents like this or should I move them to a separate collection and refer them from here inside `urlEntities?` I'm new to MongoDB, any best practices suggestion would be much helpful.

**Full Scenario:**

Say if I have a document as below in the db which has millions of data:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "51f72afa3893686e0c406e19"} , "user" : "test" , "urlEntities" : [ { "url" : "http://t.co/64HBcYmn9g" , "display_url" : "ow.ly/nqlkP" , "expanded_url" : "http://ow.ly/nqlkP"}] , "count" : 0}
```

When I get another document with similar `urlEntities` object, I need to update user and count fields only. First I thought of enforcing unique constraint on `urlEntities` fields and then handle exception and then go for an update, else if I check for each entry whether it exists before inserting, it will have significant impact on the performance. So, how can I enforce uniqueness in `urlEntities`? I tried

```
{"urlEntities.display_url":1,"urlEntities.expanded_url":1},{unique:true}
```

But still I'm able to insert the same document twice without exceptions.

Comment: Have you read about [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/addToSet/) operator?

Comment: Subdocument indexing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769705/subdocument-index-in-mongo

Comment: Good design? Really hard to know given so little information. There are lots of possibilities -- it depends on your queries you need, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Uniqueness is only enforced *per* document. You can not prevent the following (simplified from your example):

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { 'urlEntities.url' : 1 } );
db.col.insert( {
    _id: 42,
    urlEntities: [
        { 
            "url" : "http://t.co/ujBNNRWb0y"
        },
        { 
            "url" : "http://t.co/ujBNNRWb0y"
        } 
    ]
});
```

Similarily, you will have the same problem with a compound unique key for nested documents.

What you **can** do is the following:

```
db.collection.insert( {
    _id: 43,
    title: "This is an example",
} );
db.collection.update( 
    { _id: 43 },
    {
        '$addToSet': { 
            urlEntities: { 
                "url" : "http://t.co/ujBNNRWb0y" , 
                "display_url" : "bit.ly/11JyiVp" ,  
                "expanded_url" : "http://bit.ly/11JyiVp"
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Now you have the document with _id `43` with one urlEntities document. If you run the same update query **again**, it will **not** add a new array element, because the **full** combination of url, display_url and expanded_url already exists.

Also, have a look at the `$addToSet` query operator's examples: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/addToSet/

Comment: I have updated my question with full scenario after reading your answer. The first example you have given is not applicable for my requirements. Through second example, i'm not sure how i can handle insert in document level. Please check the full scenario.

Comment: The first example is just there to illustrate that uniqueness is enforced **per document** and not for **elements in a nested array** and very much applicable to your case.

Comment: Derick, a single document will not have duplicate entries inside urlEntities array. This is possible for different documents only in my case. As you have mentioned that uniqueness can be enforced per document, can you advice me on how to enforce uniqueness between urlEntities array in different document?

Answer (score 0):

for indexes on nested documents read [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#secondary-indexes).

regarding the second part (nested documents best practices) - it really depends on your business logic and queries. if those nested documents don't make sense as first class entities, meaning you won't be searching for them directly but only in the context of their parent document then having them nested make sense. otherwise you should consider extracting them out.

i think that there isn't absolute answer to your question. read the chapter about indexing... it helped me a lot.

Comment: I tried db.collection.ensureIndex( { urlEntities.url: 1, urlEntities.display_url: 1, expanded_url= 1 } ) but it throws "syntax error, unexpected token ." Also, can i ensure index when my collection is empty? like how we add unique constraint in a feild in relational database when creating the table?